# Troubleshooting Ingress Service Unavailable 503

Tags: kubernetes, raspberry-pi, traefik, kubernetes-ingress, k3s

Every request made to my my kubernetes node results in a `Ingress Service Unavailable` (503) response.

What are some different steps I should take to troubleshoot this issue?

Answer (score 5):

So if you are asking for ingress debugging steps, mine usually go along the lines of:

1. Check if Service is available internally, this could be done by running a busybox container internally and just running curl commands against the endpoint
2. Make sure that ingress selectors match the service that you have specified
3. Make sure that Pods is up and running (log the pod etc).
4. Make sure that ingress controller is not throwing errors (log the ingress controller)

It is a bit of a vague question as you could possibly have a host of issues wrong. I would say give us more info and we could better help understand your problem (i.e show use the yaml you use to configure the ingress)